# How can I add a pin marker icon on an SVG polygon element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, polygon, marker

I have na SVG Map that contains cities and their districts. You can look one of them below. I want to add a [pin icon](https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/33/33622.svg) on the center of district. You can see the text (district's name) in the middle of the district. I want to put over the text.

```html
<g id="Hakkari" transform="translate(4607.000000, 1335.000000)" data-transform-left="-521.5" data-transform-top="-87">
  <g id="Merkez" transform="translate(10.000000, 2.000000)">
    <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="31 59 119 38 181 0 193 43 155 64 163 167 49 175 0 142"></polygon>
    <g id="MER" transform="translate(85.000000, 98.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
      <text>
        <tspan x="0" y="6">MER</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Yüksekova" transform="translate(165.000000, 0.000000)">
    <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="38 44 122 0 163 7 185 27 185 107 118 133 79 177 38 176 25 190 7 168 0 66"></polygon>
    <g id="YÜK" transform="translate(78.000000, 86.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
      <text>
        <tspan x="0" y="6">YÜK</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Şemdinli" transform="translate(244.000000, 107.000000)">
    <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="106 0 168 47 172 104 121 94 40 169 14 127 31 87 0 70 39 26"></polygon>
    <g id="ŞEM" transform="translate(81.000000, 62.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
      <text>
        <tspan x="0" y="6">ŞEM</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Çukurca" transform="translate(0.000000, 143.000000)">
    <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="190 47 163 76 70 72 20 51 0 24 10 0 58 33 173 26"></polygon>
    <g id="ÇUK" transform="translate(104.000000, 50.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
      <text>  
        <tspan x="0" y="6">ÇUK</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the Google's icon "location on" as as symbol. I hope this is what you need.

```html
<svg viewBox="4600 1300 500 300">
  <defs>
  <symbol id="pin" viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>location on</title>
    <path d='M12 2c-3.87 0-7 3.13-7 7 0 5.25 7 13 7 13s7-7.75 7-13c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7zm0 9.5c-1.38 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5s1.12-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.12 2.5 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z'></path>
    <path d='M0 0h24v24h-24z' fill='none'></path>
</symbol>
</defs>
<g id="Hakkari" transform="translate(4607.000000, 1335.000000)" data-transform-left="-521.5" data-transform-top="-87">
  <g id="Merkez" transform="translate(10.000000, 2.000000)">
    <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="31 59 119 38 181 0 193 43 155 64 163 167 49 175 0 142"></polygon>
    <g id="MER" transform="translate(85.000000, 98.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
      <use xlink:href="#pin" x="-5" y="-24" width="24" height="24" />
      <text>
        <tspan x="0" y="6">MER</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Yüksekova" transform="translate(165.000000, 0.000000)">
    <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="38 44 122 0 163 7 185 27 185 107 118 133 79 177 38 176 25 190 7 168 0 66"></polygon>
    <g id="YÜK" transform="translate(78.000000, 86.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
      <use xlink:href="#pin" x="-5" y="-24" width="24" height="24" />
      <text>
        <tspan x="0" y="6">YÜK</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Şemdinli" transform="translate(244.000000, 107.000000)">
    <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="106 0 168 47 172 104 121 94 40 169 14 127 31 87 0 70 39 26"></polygon>
    <g id="ŞEM" transform="translate(81.000000, 62.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
      
      <use xlink:href="#pin" x="-5" y="-24" width="24" height="24" />
      <text>
        <tspan x="0" y="6">ŞEM</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Çukurca" transform="translate(0.000000, 143.000000)">
    <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="190 47 163 76 70 72 20 51 0 24 10 0 58 33 173 26"></polygon>
    <g id="ÇUK" transform="translate(104.000000, 50.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
      <use xlink:href="#pin" x="-5" y="-24" width="24" height="24" />
      <text>  
        <tspan x="0" y="6">ÇUK</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>

</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

In this case I'm using a png instead of an SVG path. The png is in this case square (120px/120px) with a transparent background.

```html
<svg viewBox="4600 1300 500 300">
  <symbol id="pin" viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>location on</title>
    <!--<path d='M12 2c-3.87 0-7 3.13-7 7 0 5.25 7 13 7 13s7-7.75 7-13c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7zm0 9.5c-1.38 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5s1.12-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.12 2.5 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z'></path>
    <path d='M0 0h24v24h-24z' fill='none'></path>-->
    <image width="24" height="24" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/pin.png" />
</symbol>

<g id="Hakkari" transform="translate(4607.000000, 1335.000000)" data-transform-left="-521.5" data-transform-top="-87">
  <g id="Merkez" transform="translate(10.000000, 2.000000)">
    <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="31 59 119 38 181 0 193 43 155 64 163 167 49 175 0 142"></polygon>
    <g id="MER" transform="translate(85.000000, 98.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
      <use xlink:href="#pin" x="-5" y="-24" width="24" height="24" />
      <text>
        <tspan x="0" y="6">MER</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Yüksekova" transform="translate(165.000000, 0.000000)">
    <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="38 44 122 0 163 7 185 27 185 107 118 133 79 177 38 176 25 190 7 168 0 66"></polygon>
    <g id="YÜK" transform="translate(78.000000, 86.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
      <use xlink:href="#pin" x="-5" y="-24" width="24" height="24" />
      <text>
        <tspan x="0" y="6">YÜK</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Şemdinli" transform="translate(244.000000, 107.000000)">
    <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="106 0 168 47 172 104 121 94 40 169 14 127 31 87 0 70 39 26"></polygon>
    <g id="ŞEM" transform="translate(81.000000, 62.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
      
      <use xlink:href="#pin" x="-5" y="-24" width="24" height="24" />
      <text>
        <tspan x="0" y="6">ŞEM</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Çukurca" transform="translate(0.000000, 143.000000)">
    <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="190 47 163 76 70 72 20 51 0 24 10 0 58 33 173 26"></polygon>
    <g id="ÇUK" transform="translate(104.000000, 50.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
      <use xlink:href="#pin" x="-5" y="-24" width="24" height="24" />
      <text>  
        <tspan x="0" y="6">ÇUK</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. In addition, how can i put my icon (PNG) instead of Google's icon?

Comment: I solve problem with <image> tag, thanks for solution. So, How can I add this <image> tag after 2nd <g> element with Jquery or Javascript ? I have tried with jQuery and I can see it in source code. But, It doesn't show on map. Why ?

Comment: First of all, @enxaneta thank you so much for all your solution. Finally, how can i add ``<use xlink:href="#pin" x="-5" y="-24" width="24" height="24" />`` this code with jQuery or JS? I dont want to add one by one manually.

Comment: This is an other question. please ask an other question. I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Please take a look at this example where I'm adding a pin for MER, using JavaScript: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/a6426b8e8b53edca6680b17b9ffeb633?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

My idea is same as "enxaneta" below:

```
// use <path> or <use> element as you like
var pinIconNode = document.createElement("path");

// supporse the <g> element id is the city you want
var city = document.getElementById("cityName");
city.prepend(pinIconNode);
```